# Making maps and pathfinding AI

Tags: python, path-finding

I want to retrace maps from google earth these maps would then be used for calculating fastest route from A to B as well as location probability defined by some factors. How would i go about doing these? My first thought is pygame and using some already made ones or using them as a template.

Comment: Can you let me know if there is something else you'd like me to touch on? Otherwise, can you mark it as answered por favor?

Comment: Totally, i kind of dropped the project so didn't think to look here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked on a routing application for a while.  The most common algorithm for this is to start on both ends (start and finish) and move towards each other, traversing all possible methods of travel.  The branches that meet in the middle will be your ideal path.

You can weight things appropriately, like speed limit, by setting checks in the code to only move x distance every time step.

These should do you:

[Good graph traversal algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320688/good-graph-traversal-algorithm/)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm/

[Map Routing, a la Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798/map-routing-a-la-google-maps/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Google Maps, rather than Google Earth? This has roads and a routing engine.

Comment: The thing is i want sidewalks and other stuff thats not on google maps

Comment: Its still not detailed enough and i can't look for possible locations based on speed/vector/other variables. So google maps is not an option and i might possibly do other stuff with it later.