# In Android Studio, how to use Google Maps route API as a gRPC?

Tags: android, google-maps, grpc, google-maps-api-2

In this page ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/compute_route_directions?hl=ko#java ), describes the gRPC communication method.
But I can't apply this to Android.
Is this a technique that's not supposed to work on Android?

An error occurred in google.maps.routing, so I can't start it.
Please help me ~

I want to implement the route finding function in Android using gRPC.

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpcyK.jpg)

Comment: You may use Google Maps APIs, including the Directions API for retrieving routes. check this for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798/map-routing-a-la-google-maps

Comment: Your question lacks detail and an minimal reproduction of your issue. Please add these so that we may help. What does "I can't apply this to Android" mean? What "error occurred in google.maps.routing"?

Comment: @DazWilkin, In the above article URL, I copied the code corresponding to the "Example: gRPC request" - java section to android. In this case, it meant that an error occurred in the import part. Thank you for asking.

How can I use this gRPC on Android!!

Comment: @Maveňツ, Thank you. However, the Direciton API is old and I can't seem to find anything about gRPC. Thank you for pointing me in a different direction.

Comment: The Java example in Google's documentation is poor. I'm not a Java dev and I'm unfamiliar with Google's Routes API but I can provide some pointers. Google generally provides SDKs for its services. If these aren't available for this service for Java, you can generate these from Google's sources: [`ComputeRoutes`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/232e5625d4ab08129843ab5a6402ae1f0fe3f585/google/maps/routing/v2/routes_service.proto#L87) is here. I encourage you to explore the documentation [basic tutorial gRPC in Android Java](https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/android/java/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the
[Google Routes API Client for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/main/java-maps-routing)
(linked from the [Routes API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/client-libraries) documentation)
so you can

```java
import com.google.maps.routing.v2.*;
```